# How to set border of Shapes inside Word Document to None using c#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

i've created a label in a Word Document like this

```
    public void CreateLabel(string LabelName, int left, int top, int width, int height, string text)
    {
        var oRange = currentDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item("\\endofdoc").Range;
        var oshape = oRange.Document.Shapes.AddLabel(MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, left, top, width, height);

        oshape.Name = LabelName;
        oshape.TextFrame.ContainingRange.Borders.OutsideLineStyle=WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone;
        oshape.TextFrame.ContainingRange.Text = text;
        oshape.TextFrame.ContainingRange.Font.Size = 14;
    }
```

but it never sets border to none.what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good [article](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidesnet/Formatting+Lines+of+the+Shapes) about Formatting Lines of the Shapes.you can find something about line formathing there,and this is the solution of my problem.hope it's useful for some one else.

```
  oshape.Line.Visible = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
```